# HOW TO DOWNLOAD A STRINGIFIED BLOB FROM REACT NATIVE TO MY WEB APP

Tags: firebase, react-native, download, blob, cryptojs

I have just uploaded a stringified blob in my firebase storage. It is stringified because it is being encrypted using CryyptoJS. My problem is everytime I attempt a download in my web app I can see this type of value. My question is how do I download this blob because I cant seem to use this blob as a parameter for the window.URL.createObjectURL. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Can't you proceed with decoding?

Comment: hello @hongdeveloper, what do you mean by decoding?

Comment: Because you encrypted the data, if not one-way encryption, you can get the original data through decoding.

Comment: That is already the decoded value @hongdeveloper from cyptoJS. I just parsed it to JSON. that is the value before it is being stringified in my react native app.